# Type Assertions not Working when Reading Firestore Data

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to read a complex document from Firebase in order to do some calculations and then execute a Cloud Function.

Unfortunately, I am unable to read the data in the data types that I would like.

Here is an example:

```
interface CourseEvent {
  coucourseGroupType: string;
  date: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp;
  courseGroupTypeFirebaseId: string;
  firebaseId: string;
  maxParticipants: number;
  participants: Participant[];
  start: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp;
  waitingList: Participant[];
  weekNumber: string;
}
```

This is where I am using the Cloud Function

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { firestore, Timestamp, FieldValue } from "./setup";

export const registerCustomerFromWaitingList = functions.firestore
  .document("CourseEvents/{courseEvent}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const currentCourseEvent = change.after.data() as CourseEvent;
    const currentMaxParticipants = currentCourseEvent.maxParticipants;
    if (typeof currentMaxParticipants === "number") {
     console.log(`currentMaxParticipants type is number`);
    } else if (typeof currentMaxParticipants === "string") {
     console.log(`currentMaxParticipants type is string`);
    } else {
     console.log(`currentMaxParticipants type is NOT number or string`);
    }
   }
```

The console always prints that the `currentMaxParticipants`  is a **string**. I have a similar problem also with another interface.

I also have experimented with such code

```
const nu = change.after.data().maxParticipants as number;
```

But in the end, I am still getting a string.

Any tips?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the document you're working with.  You could provide a screenshot that clearly shows the field value that isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why I would get always a `string` for the `currentMaxParticipants` variable.

In Firestore I did save it as a `string`. I thought that by using type assertions I would also convert the value. In the end, I did change the value within Firestore to a `number` and now it is working.

I just read this here:

*Essential TypeScript: From Beginner to Pro*

> **CAUTION** No type conversion is performed by a type assertion, which only tells the compiler what type it should apply to a value for the
> purposes of type checking.

Comment: This is why I asked to see a screenshot of the document.  It would be clear from looking at the document in the console what type of data it will provide.